# Apache2 send response while waiting for HDD to spin up

Tags: windows, nginx, apache-2.4, apache2

I have an Apache 2.4 Server that hosts static files. One directory (`example.com/`) is on the SDD (System-drive) and anotherone is on an external HDD (`example.com/ef/`).

My Problem is that because my HDD is external it shuts off, when it is not used for about 2 Minutes. If a request comes to `/ef/` the HDD has to spin up and that can take up to 15 Seconds.

I have 4 solution approaches, but don't know if they are possible:
While the HDD spins up...

1. show some kind of text in the browser, while it is loading and then replace it with the actual content. The Problem may be that most of the content on the HDD are not text.
2. same as 1 but take the text from a file (SSD)
3. serve a HTML that auto-redirects to the same url after x seconds
4. redirect to another path that auto-redirects to the original url after x seconds (redirect url in header?)

If none of these are possible in apache, but in **nginx**, I will switch to that instead.

Thanks in advance
Der_Mueller

Comment: Or get a drive that will actually not go to sleep in two minutes. I'm voting to close this question as it's far removed from best practices.